# Which way is better, CookieHandler or org.apache.http.cookie?

Tags: java, android

I want to make thumbnail of youtube cookie using youtube API.
 After searching on google I found two ways to implement cookie in Android. 
 [CookieHandler](http://www.androiddocs.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/package-summary.html) and [org.apache.http.cookie](http://www.androiddocs.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/package-summary.html).
Which way is more better, [CookieHandler](http://www.androiddocs.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/package-summary.html) or [org.apache.http.cookie](http://www.androiddocs.com/reference/org/apache/http/cookie/package-summary.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Apache library to perform HTTP calls (so all the classes in package `org.apache.http.**`) have been deprecated/removed in Android 6, details [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes#behavior-apache-http-client)

So it's better if you use [CookieManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager)/[CookieHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieHandler) to handle Cookies now.